# Copying worksheets error: copy area and paste area aren't the same size

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I created code to copy all 25 dynamic sheets on the first sheet named "All-PID" using a loop.

I was able to run earlier very long code, now stuck on an error message.

```vb
Sub Consolidation()
    
    'Create All-PID Worksheet
    
    Sheets("PMCC-1").Select
    Sheets("PMCC-1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("PMCC-1 (2)").Select
    Sheets("PMCC-1 (2)").Name = "All-PID"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Copy PMCC-2 upto PMCC-25 to "All-PID" Worksheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        If ws.Name <> "PMCC-1" Then 
            Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim iLastCellS1 As Excel.Range
            Dim iLastRowS2 As Long
    
            Set s1 = Sheets("All-PID")
            Set s2 = ActiveSheet
    
            iLastRowS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set iLastCellS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            s2.Range("A2", s2.Cells(iLastRowS2, "W")).Copy iLastCellS1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Seems to get stuck on `s2.Range("A2", s2.Cells(iLastRowS2, "W")).Copy iLastCellS1`.

Error message is

> Run time Error '1004'
> "You can't paste this here because the copy area and paste area aren't
> the same size".

Comment: Possibly unrelated to the problem, but a note: 1) Shouldn't `s2` be `ws`? And 2) If you don't exclude `Sheets("All-PID")`, it will be processed in the loop, i.e. at some point it will be `ws`,  and I assume that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your code into something that should work and is more sustainable. I have commented in some of the principles of coding VBA Excel that I have modified.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidation()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create All-PID Worksheet
    '**** - Work directly with object ***
    Worksheets("PMCC-1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)

    Dim pmcc As Worksheet
    Set pmcc = ActiveSheet
    pmcc.Name = "All-PID"

    'Copy PMCC-2 upto PMCC-25 to "All-PID" Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> pmcc.Name Then

            With ws '**** - No need to recreate variables ... also with block can make code easier to read and write and understand***

                Dim lastRow As Long
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                Dim copyRange As Range
                Set copyRange = .Range("A2:W" & lastRow)

            End With

            With pmcc '**** - resize is VERY useful. I assume you don't need formulas copied, if so, i can edit answer
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value
            End With

        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried running the modified code but  producing an error on the line "Set pmcc = Worksheets("PMCC-1").Copy(Before:=Sheets(1))"

Answer (score 1):

Two worksheets ("All-PID" and "PMCC-1") should have been excluded from the loop since the content of "PMCC-1" is already in "All-PID" sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Consolidation()
    
    Worksheets("PMCC-1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("PMCC-1 (2)").Select
    Sheets("PMCC-1 (2)").Name = "All-PID"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Dim wsDest As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
               
    Set wsDest = Sheets("All-PID")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case Is = "All-PID", "PMCC-1"
        Case Else
            Dim iLastRowS2 As Long
            iLastRowS2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Dim iLastCellS1 As Excel.Range
            Set iLastCellS1 = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
            ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(iLastRowS2, "W")).Copy iLastCellS1

        End Select
            
    Next ws

End Sub
```